# Message from RabbitMQ client doesn't get pattern matched

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I'm trying to subscribe to a RabbitMQ queue like explained [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/erlang-client-user-guide.html#subscribing). I can get the messages in my process but somehow it doesn't get pattern matched to the first function clause.

```
handle_info({#'basic.deliver'{delivery_tag = Tag}, #amqp_msg{payload = Payload}}, {Channel, Tag, Module} = State) ->
    amqp_channel:cast(Channel, #'basic.ack'{delivery_tag = Tag}),
    gen_server:start_link(Module, Payload, []),
    {noreply, State};
handle_info(Message, State) -> 
    lager:info("~p", [Message]),
    {noreply, State}.
```

My code looks identical to a [few examples I found on Github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%23%27basic.deliver%27%20language%3Aerlang&type=Code) but the message always ends up in the second clause. Here's the log message.

> [info]
>   {{'basic.deliver',<<"amq.ctag-7EUw07D8SQ5cSX9DaVBznw">>,1,true,<<"trail">>,<<"SlackUserCreated">>},{amqp_msg,{'P_basic',undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined},<<"{\"userId\":32,\"returnUrl\":\"http://example.org\"}">>}}

Clearly I'm missing something obvious here. This is the [RabbitMQ client](https://github.com/jbrisbin/amqp_client) I'm using.

Comment: Is the `Tag` in the state tuple equal to the delivery tag?

Comment: @legoscia They are not equal, that was the problem. Please post an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function head, you're using the variable `Tag` twice, once in the `basic.deliver` record and once in the state.  It looks like this message should match otherwise, so probably the tag in the state is not equal to the delivery tag.